# How to add keywords to search preferences in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preference

I added a preference by using this example:
 http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool/Eclipse%20UI%20Examples%20Readme%20Tool/org/eclipse/ui/examples/readmetool/

For the actual reference refer to this page: 
http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.ui.git/plain/examples/org.eclipse.ui.examples.readmetool/Eclipse%20UI%20Examples%20Readme%20Tool/org/eclipse/ui/examples/readmetool/ReadmePreferencePage.java )

I only added one checkbox to test it, when I search any word in the checkbox in Preferences I do not see my view coming up but if I type something that currently Eclipse has, then it comes up (i.e. I type background and I can see the *General* tab staying and being bold).

I guess I somehow need to add search keywords to point to the current page (or something else). But I couldn't find how to add that, or what causes this problem.

So how can I perform searches within the *Preferences* window for preferences that I have created?

Comment: if your page title is displayed in the tree (left part of preferencedialog) and can access it through it, then searching for the title in the searchbox should be automatic

Comment: @flafoux searching the title works, what doesn't work is what's in the preference page.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a `org.eclipse.ui.keywords` extension point that allows to define keywords that can be assigned to a preference page.

For example:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.preferencePages"> 
  <page id="com.xyz.prefpage1" name="XYZ" class="..."> 
     <keywordReference id="xyz.Keyword"/>
  </page> 
</extension> 
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.keywords">
  <keyword label="foo" id="xyz.Keyword"/>
</extension>
```

With the above extension, the *XYZ* preference page can also be found under the keyword *foo*, i.e. it will be listed when you type *foo* in the search field.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks.  Sadly the Eclipse team rejected the suggestion to search the prefs pane contents: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=203271